# Multiple email sender - every mail address receives more then one message

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a program that sends an email message to multiple email addresses. The problem is that when I send the message every mail address receives more then one message. If I have 5 email addresses, the program sends 5 messages to each email address. How can i solve this? This is my code:

```
Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
    Dim trd As Threading.Thread
    trd = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf mailBomber)
    trd.isBackground = True
    trd.Start()
End Sub

Private Function mailBomber()
    Dim sent As Integer = 0
    Dim toSend As Integer = 5
    Do Until sent >= toSend
        Try
            Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
            Dim mail As New MailMessage()
            SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(emailFrom.Text, emailPass.Text)
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True
            SmtpServer.Port = 587
            SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
            mail = New MailMessage()
            mail.From = New MailAddress(emailFrom.Text)
            mail.To.Add(emailTo.Text)
            mail.Subject = subject.Text
            mail.Body = msg.Text
            SmtpServer.Send(mail)
            sent += 1
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    Loop
End Function
```

Comment: What is the value of emailTo.Text ?

Comment: Get rid of that loop.  If you only want to send one message then only send one message.  If you have multiple addresses to send that one message to then you add multiple addresses to the `To` property of that one message.  You're already doing that because the `String` you pass is a delimited list of multiple email addresses. In short, the reason people are getting multiple messages is that you're sending multiple messages. Don't and they won't.

Comment: @mcilhinney yeah you're right  thank you very  very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with VBA using the concept below.

Make a list in Sheets("Sheet1") with :

In column A : Names of the people In column B : E-mail addresses In column C:Z : Filenames like this C:\Data\Book2.xls (don't have to be Excel files)

The Macro will loop through each row in "Sheet1" and if there is a E-mail address in column B and file name(s) in column C:Z it will create a mail with this information and send it.

```
Sub Send_Files()
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim FileCell As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each cell In sh.Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

        'Enter the path/file names in the C:Z column in each row
        Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("C1:Z1")

        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            With OutMail
                .to = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Testfile"
                .Body = "Hi " & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value

                For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                    If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                        If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                            .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                        End If
                    End If
                Next FileCell

                .Send  'Or use .Display
            End With

            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

    Set OutApp = Nothing
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```